# Multiplicative order of $2$ modulo $p$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, multiplicative-order

When calculating the multiplicative order of $2$ modulo a prime $p$ you often get $p-1$ or $\frac{p-1}{2}$ as a result, but there are cases where this does not hold, is there a general form for those primes for which this does not hold?. For example, the order of $2$ modulo $89$ is $11$, why is that so?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  Nobody knows if, say, $2$ is a primitive root for infinitely many primes (though it would be a huge surprise if it isn't).

Comment: The multiplicative order of $2$ modulo odd prime $p$ will always be a divisor of $p-1$, which can vary depending on $p$.

Comment: @SammyBlack Technically the MO of *any* integer mod *any* prime $p$ will be a divisor of $p-1$, ignoring of course values congruent to $0 \pmod p$.

Comment: If $p$ is a Mersenne prime then the order of $2$ mod $p$ is relatively tiny.

Answer (score 3):

Using the first $5000$ or so primes, we find that the multiplicative order of smaller primes mod $p$ is distributed very similarly for all the primes, not just $2$. On average, a given prime has a multiplicative order of $(p-1)/k$ with approximately proportion $p$:

$$
\begin{array}{c c} 
k=1 & p \approx 37 \% \\
k=2 & p \approx 27 \% \\ 
k=3 & p \approx 7 \% \\ 
k=4 & p \approx 7 \% \\ 
\end{array}
$$

and then generally decreasing.

Surprising result: the value of $k$ for $5$ is *never* an odd multiple of $5$, no matter the modulus.

Comment: The "surprising result" will hold with $5$ replaced by any prime $q$ of the form $4m+1$. Suppose that $k$ (for the prime $q$) is a multiple of $q$ for some modulus $p$. That means that $q$ is a $q$th power modulo $p$, or equivalently that the polynomial $X^q-q$ splits into linear factors modulo $p$. But it is known that $\Bbb Q(\sqrt q) \subset \Bbb Q(e^{2\pi i/q},\sqrt[p]p)$, and therefore $X^2-q$ also splits into linear factors modulo $p$, which forces $q$ to be a quadratic residue modulo $p$. This is the same hiccup that required a correction to Artin's primitive root conjecture.